# HTML canvas fillRect with low opacity doesn't affect dark pixels

Tags: html5-canvas

Repeatedly drawing a semi-opaque black rectangle over the entire canvas before each animation frame is an easy way to get an afterimage effect for moving shapes and it gives me exactly what I need - up to a point.  With too slow a fade it doesn't fade all the way to black.  Here's an example:

```
var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canv);
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 60);

window.requestAnimationFrame(doFade);

function doFade() {
    // Never fades away completely
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02)';  
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doFade);  
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/madsci/z7ocznen/)

This looks to me like a numeric precision problem - you can't expect the canvas to keep floating point pixel values around - but I'm not sure how to get around this.

I tried reading the image into a pattern, blanking the canvas, and then filling with the pattern at lower opacity in the hope that I could make rounding error work in my favor, but it seems to have the same result.

Short of reading out the image data and setting to black any pixels below a certain threshold, which would be prohibitively slow, I'm running out of ideas and could use some suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. in this site each problem presented need to be specific so it can be answered with a specific answer if possible. Your question as it is now (asking for ideas) is considered Too broad or Opinion based. so please could you edit it to be specific to one problem (maybe try to implement one of your ideas and ask about the problem you got stuck on).

Comment: The problem is still a little abstract. Could you include some exemplary code that replicates your situation?

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing and added code and a jsfiddle.  One click should be enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Would it be ok to use a simple [counter](https://jsfiddle.net/s4o1es50/6/)?

Comment: No, I don't see how a counter could be used here.  The issue is that there's a shape moving continuously in the canvas and leaving fresh trails.  It's the oldest trails that need to be removed, without tracking many frames of history.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd share my solution for the benefit of anyone else who might run into this problem.  I was hoping to avoid doing any pixel-level manipulation, but beyond a certain threshold it's just not possible with the built-in canvas operations because the underlying bitmap is only 8 bits per channel and small fades will work out to less than one least significant bit and won't have any effect on the image data.

My solution was to create an array representing the age of each pixel.  After each frame is drawn, I scan the imageData array, looking only at the alpha channel.  If the alpha is 255 I know the pixel has just been written, so I set the age to 0 and set the alpha to 254.  For any other non-zero alpha values, I increment the pixel age and then set the new alpha based on the pixel age.

The mapping of pixel age to alpha value is done with a lookup table that's populated when the fade rate is set.  This lets me use whatever decay curve I want without extra math during the rendering loop.

The CPU utilization is a bit higher, but it's not too much of a performance hit and it can do smooth fades over several seconds and always fades entirely to black eventually.